# How to make a UI for calendar with vacancy?

Tags: dates, calendar

I am building a website for a tour company. There is a tour every day and the maximum number of participants is 20.

1) How would you show the dates with with taken+available places that there are for each day?

2) Since prices are different for each day, how can I add a price for the tour for that day as well?

Comment: Check out http://fullcalendar.io/. We use it on our site for booking services and shared amenities - I think it does an exceptional job of a fairly tricky problem!

Comment: Can you post a mockup/screenshot of your attempt?

Comment: Thanks @Amilia Schmidt, but it does not excatly fit my needs. I am looking to write available/taken places for each days and not the events. In addition, I wnat to write a price in each day...

Comment: Thanks @Adit Gupta, unfortunately, I dont have something in mind yet since I am not a designer and no clue how to approach this...and this is why I decided to ask the more experience members of the community here.

Comment: @Yura You'll get a lot more engagement if you show some work towards a solution. Appreciate you're looking for help, but there is usually a lot of implicit knowledge in any problem, and showing a solution even as a starting point can be a big help.

Comment: how many are the max available places? and, is there more than 1 event per day in the calendar view?

Comment: there are max 20 places. yes tgere is only 1 tour per day

Answer (score 2):

I'm going with the assumption all calendar days offer the same tour, 1 tour a day, happening at the exact same time. But some days are more expensive than others. Price is set per person/seat. You would like visitors to sign up for a seat.

Because you're showing a couple pieces of info for each day. It's likely going to be too cluttered/confusing to try and pack all of this into a single calendar. I would recommend a 2 page approach to help solve probably your main goal of getting visitors to sign up.

Something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG7sqG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The basic info that influence the visitor's decision goes onto the calendar: Date Available, Price, # of Seats remaining. Then if the visitor is interested in a particular date, they click into the details page for the day. That'll allow them to read up on the particulars of that day's tour, including time, tour size/number of people already signed up etc. This will lead naturally to your call-to-action at the end there for them to move on with signing up/booking.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the a couple of things, but because it's a calendar I'd probably make sure that you saw a month view with a small link that displays how many available slots there are left on every single day. Any full days should be highlighted in a different color, with potentially the option to reserve a spot if anyone cancels.

Then when selecting the link to sign up for an available slot, it would show a day/week view with all currently taken slots, and users should be prompted to click in open spots.

Calend.ly is a good example of some of these, and various other tools have other functions I suggest, like Asana.